# Unable to execute Postgres queries when running with uWSGI

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, uwsgi

I have a basic flask application in which I am connecting with a local Postgres server.

The problem is that the application works fine when I run it using python manager. But when I use uWSGI to run application, the query doesn't executes i.e., it timeouts without throwing any error message.

I have a relatively simple wsgi configuration file like

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 1

http = 0.0.0.0:5000
buffer-size = 32768
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

My flask application uses `psycopg2` to connect with localhost like

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=5432,
        database='db',
        user='user',
        password='password'
    )
```

I think this might probably be happening because postgresql socket is not accessible by uWSGI ([reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why)). I believe this can be solved by providing postgres socket permission to uWSGI, but I am unable to figure out how. If there is another solution than that will also work.

Comment: please provide uwsgi logs?
probably at `/var/log/uwsgi`.

Comment: It just shows my application logs, without any uwsgi specific errors. The application timeouts at `cursor.execute()` line.

Comment: probably issue with postgres configuration. did you fix?

Comment: Postgres connects fine as I am able to query when running application without uWSGI. It seems to be a problem about socket permissions